# Google cloud engine, ssh between two centos7 instances fails

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

I've setup 2 Google Compute Engine instances and I can easily SSH in both of them by using the key created by **gcloud compute ssh** command. But when I try the following...

```
myself@try-master ~] ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
myself@try-master ~] cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
myself@try-master ~] chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
myself@try-master ~] ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub myself@try-slave-1
```

... it does not work, and ssh-copy-id shows the message below:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

If I copy the google_compute_engine private and public key on try-master, and can use it to log on both instances, but I find unsatisfactory to move a private key over the network. I guess this is somewhat related to this [topic](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#sshbetweeninstances):

How can this be solved?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#sshbetweeninstances

Answer (score 2):

1. Using CentOS7 images, and a CentOs7 as local host:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances create try-master --image centos-7
   gcloud compute instances create try-slave-1 --image centos-7
   ```

This can be solved by using authentication forwarding during initial SSH keys setup:

2. Set up authentication forwarding for once on local machine (note the "-A" flag). First you need to run:

   `` eval `ssh-agent -s` ``

   And then

   ```
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
   gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag="-A" try-master
   ```
3. Perform the steps above (from keygen to ssh-copy-id) 

   `myself@try-master ~] ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   myself@try-master ~] cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   myself@try-master ~] chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   myself@try-master ~] ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub myself@try-slave-1
   myself@try-master ~] exit`
4. Login again into try-master without SSH authentication forwarding:

   `gcloud compute ssh try-master
   myself@try-master ~] ssh myself@try-slave-1
   myself@try-slave-1 ~]`

Initial approach didn't work because GCE instances only allow public key authentication by default. So, ssh-copy-id is unable to authenticate against try-slave to copy the new public key, because there is no public key configured in try-master available in try-slave yet.

Using authentication forwarding, the private key from your local machine is forwarded from your local machine to try-master, and from there to try-slave. GCE account manager in try-slave will fetch the public key from your project metadata and thus ssh-copy-id will be able to copy work.

Comment: I have re-posted your response as "answer", to close this question.

Comment: This still fails for me
    `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub name@instance`
        `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed`
        `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys`
    `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

Comment: I just checked again and it worked well.... I am editing the answer and replacing `eval $(ssh-agent)` by `eval \`ssh-agent -s\``